# if determinant of a matix is negative then how many solutions are possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
     2   & -1   & 3\\
     3   & -2   & 5\\
     -1  & 4    & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is the matrix for which I am getting determinant in negative.

Comment: How many solution of what?

Comment: Solutions like unique solution or infinite or no solution. I have extracted this matrix from liner equations with 3 unkowns.

Comment: If the determinant is negative it is non zero hence there is a unique solution.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat .... Earlier I was in doubt but know I am confirmed of this fact. Thanks.